# Freqent connection lost with PS3 connected to Beaglebone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I'm controlling a DC motor and `PS3` controller with `Beaglebone Black`. For PS3 I'm using [this](https://github.com/drewnoakes/joystick) git repo.

DC motor and PS3 works fine with BBB and using `jstest` for monitoring PS3 but when motor applies some impulsive torque or stops mometorily, PS3 hangs or its connection lost to BBB.

I won't be able to get reading form `jstest`. I have to restart BBB to make PS3 work again.
Can someone tell me what's going on and how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT power high loads directly from the BBB! Use the io pins to control a FET or a relay and make sure the power supply is sized sufficiently and possibly add some larger capacitors to buffer supply voltage drops. Or even better use a separate supply for each.

Comment: I'm using a 5v power jack (step down using 12 to 5 convertor) to power BBB. Is there any better way to power BBB using some capacitor or something.

Comment: For more information, please reread my posting. You must power the motor and the BBB *separately*.